# How do I override chef-client configuration on node?

Tags: chef-infra

My cookbook under "attributes" folder in default.rb contains lines below, I have chef-client::config in my runlist but this setting never makes it to a node, what am I missing here?

```
default['chef_client']['interval'] = '180'
```

Comment: https://docs.chef.io/attributes.html#attribute-precedence

Comment: Per document putting force_override['chef_client']['interval'] = '180' supposed to have highest precendence but is still does not work

Answer (score -1):

You already got multiple, in-depth answers on the mailing list. Don't cross post questions, especially ones already answered.

For others the find this via Google: Check your attribute ordering and remember that node data is only saved back to the server after a converge completes successfully.

Comment: My question was not answered. See my last post in original thread. I still don't know how to modify chef-client parameters via attribute file. I got it working only when I specify attributes for my Role on chef server. I need this to be in attribute file instead.

Comment: Then your attribute file is probably either in the wrong place, not being processed, or contains the wrong code. You can find the Chef tutorials at learn.chef.io which go over using attribute files. The fact that you are configuring chef-client itself is irrelevant.

Comment: Well I think I did everything per what Chef told me to do and it still does not work. I put following info to be written to log `Chef::Log.info("interval is set to " +  node['chef_client']['interval'] ` which writes out as `[2016-05-19T17:33:19-07:00] INFO: interval is set to 180` while service still informs that run will be in 1800 s `[2016-05-19T17:33:58-07:00] INFO: Next chef-client run will happen in 1800.0273541086358 seconds`

Comment: Community support is not about giving you the specific things to do to make Chef behave the way you want. If that is the level of support you are looking for, you need to pay someone. As we've all explained, attribute files in cookbooks get merged in to the node object. Beyond that, it's up to how you wrote your code.

Comment: I think I can decide for myself what community support is for. If you are unwilling or unwanting to help you can just stop commenting on my post. Your point of view are of no interest to me.

Comment: @GSA we're happy to help people showing a minimal effort to take in account advices. You're exhibiting the typical [HelpVampire](http://communitymgt.wikia.com/wiki/Help_Vampire) behavior, I'm less tight about it on the mailing than here on SO. If you can't cope with StackOverflow guidelines you should not ask here. Read the [tour] please and do us a favor by reading the links given before asking for more details. If you want us to do the work for you, hire us.

Comment: All of this is open to interpretation. I did in fact search google and documentation before asking questions. And I don't believe I'm out of guidelines asking questions and clarifications. Obviously answers provided to me were not sufficient for me to figure out how do I do certain stuff in Chef and I still don't understand why stuff does not work as it's supposed to.